# Are DNS settings on Windows 10 per access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, dns

On Windows 10, I've gone into my network settings (Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network connections) and chose my WiFi adapter.

In the properties, I changed the settings for IPv4, choosing to obtain an IP address automatically, but specifying specific DNS servers. I did the same thing for IPv6.

When at home, I can confirm that the custom DNS settings are being used. However, when connecting to another access point via WiFi, the custom DNS settings are not being respected.

I assumed that the DNS settings would be across all access points (assuming the Wifi adapter is used). But now I'm wondering if this setting is defined per access point?

I do see my network name underneath WiFi adapter, so that makes me wonder.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I now know that DNS settings work across access points.  What confused me (other than the network name underneath the WiFi adapter) was that the DNS features I was expecting were only working on a single access point.  But it turns out the DNS was getting set across access points, but it's just that the features needed to be tied to a single public IP to get the enhanced DNS features I was expecting (filtering using NextDNS, in this case).